# Add extra field on "File Upload" widget of OctoberCMS

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I want to add an extra field to the **Upload Files** widget,
how I can do that?

---

What I actually have:

- I changed DB (hardcoded on phpMyAdmin) [image: IMG0]
- This is an updated `_config_form.htm` [image: IMG1]
- And I have added this to `FileUpload.php` [image: IMG2]

---

Error on saving:
[image: IMG3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on the name of the new field...

So If change "data" to for example "params" all will work great:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should not edit any core files directly, better way would be to create plugin, inside plugin create formwidget that extends from FileUpload.php give your widget an alias and use that alias instead of fileupload.

To add another field before $file->save() just override onSaveAttachmentConfig() method and that's it.

Problem with FileUpload is that it reads config from partial and not from config so it's hard to extend view that's pesented to users.

At least it was case with me, a had to add tags, taglist field and image crop inside multi image upload widget.

It was really complicated.